Which OSes adhere to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)?
There's no list in existence of the distributions which claim (and are) adherent to the FHS - solely those which do not.
The idea came from this SU question (permalink).

This is not asking for a software recommendation.

@Alejandro, how? I've never hard of an OS not being considered software, if that's what you mean.

OSs are certainly software and we ca ask suggestion about them (it has been done numerous times on this forum). However, there is no such question here, just a mention about a list of some characteristic. If you want a recommendation about a particular OS, the include your requirements here in the question. See How to ask.

@Alejandro, the characteristic is merely adherence to the FHS. That's only a characteristic of a subset of OSes - none of the VAX, early UNIX (Sun Micrososystems', for instance) nor MS-DOS (Windows 95) or NT (Windows 11) OSes support it. Nor do some UNIX derivatives like some BSDs (macOS's Darwin, for instance). Consequently, I'm interested in OSes that do and do not support it, because non-Linux OSes that adhere usually have a reason, just as Linux-based ones that don't do. Does that make sense?

Compliant




Name
Version
Kernel




Arch Linux
>= 2024.07.01
Linux


SUSE Linux Enterprise
>= 15.4
Linux


Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)
>= 9
Linux


Fedora
>= 40
Linux


Ubuntu
>= 24.04
Linux


Debian
>= 12 (Bookworm) ^Debian_citation
Linux


openSUSE Tumbleweed

Linux



I've included the kernel to demonstrate that non-Linux based OSes can adhere to the FHS (like BSD). However, I don't know of any which do. Please add them if so.
Non-Compliant


Linux-based




Name
Version




GoboLinux
<= 017


NixOS
<= 24.05


The Android Open Source Project (AOSP)
<= 14 ^AOSP_citation




Non-Linux-based

For those who aren't technically competent enough to know intuitively:



Name
Version
Kernel




Windows
>= 98. 95 was a DE atop MS-DOS.
NT


macOS ^macOS_citation

Darwin (BSD)


MS-DOS (Disk Operating System)

Monolithic





Cross-posts


https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/781094/386242
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690513/386242

